# linker error using external FreeVerb C++ classes in iOS project

Tags: c++, ios, linker

i'm trying to use the [freeverb reverberation library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeverb3/) in an audio synthesis project.
i've added the source files to the Xcode project, but when i want to use a class from the library, i get a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"fv3::nrevb_::nrevb_()", referenced from:
  -[FreeVerbModule .cxx_construct] in FreeVerbModule.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Should i worry about the i386 architecture thing?
i don't know much about C++ and was hoping to just use the library. It makes use of a lot of C++ stuff that i can't really read and has the following includes:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <new>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>
```

the project built successfully, do i still have to add these to the project?

excuse my noobness.

Comment: Were you able to get freeverb to work on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you experiencing a 32 vs. 64 bit issue as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703792/ld-symbols-not-found-when-linking)?

Comment: i don't know :] , i just naively added the FreeVerb source files to my project and thought it would hopefully do the right thing when compiling.. do you think i would need to recompile its dependencies to 32 bit?